# The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context. I'm going crazy?

Tags: sql

I can't solve this problem. I just installed SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and I did everything like developers on various videos did (I installed and removed it a couple of times). I tried solutions on the internet and none of them worked. It's important for me to solve this problem as soon as possible so please help me.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. If your computer name has some of these letters ć,č,š,ž,đ, or similar, try changing it. Use the English alphabet to be sure.

Comment: Please click the Green check mark to the left of your answer to signpost it to others "as answered".